# Problem with multiple OpenID's?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

So I have my account on several sites, but sometimes when I go to other sites it recognizes other accounts?  Can you just sync them all to this account?  I'm not sure why its happening.

Comment: email details to the email link at the bottom of every page.. there's no value in having user-specific things here, but feel free to email us.